# convert data spread in each 2 row to only one row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe where each 2 rows represent a sport match ond their odds and movement..

```
col1            col2    col3    col4    col5
05/22 16:30     1.2     6       9       500.00%
Croatia 3.HNL   4.333   5       1.5 
05/23 14:00     1.222   5.5     9       80.00%
Kosovo Super    1.444   4.5     5
```

I want to represent each match in one row only
like below

```
match_time      competition     odd1_open   odd1_close  odd2_open   odd2_close  odd3_open   odd3_close  movement
05/22 16:30     Croatia 3.HNL   1.2         4.333       6           5           9           1.5         500.00%
05/23 14:00     Kosovo Super    1.222       1.444       5.5         4.5         9           5           80.00%
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.merge` and `DataFrame.iloc`

```
df = pd.merge(df.iloc[::2, :].reset_index() ,df.iloc[1::2, :].reset_index(), \
         left_index=True, right_index=True).drop(['index_x','index_y','col5_y'], axis=1).iloc[:,[0,5,1,6,2,7,3,8,4]]

df.columns = ['match_time', 'competition', 'odd1_open', 'odd1_close', 'odd2_open', 'odd2_close', 'odd3_open', 'odd3_close', 'movement']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) on axis 1:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['05/22 16:30', 'Croatia 3.HNL', '05/23 14:00', 'Kosovo Super'],
    'col2': [1.2, 4.333, 1.222, 1.444], 'col3': [6.0, 5.0, 5.5, 4.5],
    'col4': [9.0, 1.5, 9.0, 5.0], 'col5': ['500.00%', np.nan, '80.00%', np.nan]
})

s = df.index // 2
df = (
    df.set_index([s, df.groupby(s).cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
)

df.columns = ['match_time', 'competition', 'odd1_open', 'odd1_close',
              'odd2_open', 'odd2_close', 'odd3_open', 'odd3_close', 'movement']
print(df.to_string())
```

`df`:

```
    match_time    competition  odd1_open  odd1_close  odd2_open  odd2_close  odd3_open  odd3_close movement
0  05/22 16:30  Croatia 3.HNL      1.200       4.333        6.0         5.0        9.0         1.5  500.00%
1  05/23 14:00   Kosovo Super      1.222       1.444        5.5         4.5        9.0         5.0   80.00%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) on the 2 portions of `df[0::2]` and `df[1::2]` (after [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) of them).  Sort the column names with [`.sort_index(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html). Drop the empty column of 2nd line of `col5` with [`.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). Finally, rename the columns, as follows:

```
df1 = (df[0::2].reset_index(drop=True)
               .join(
                     df[1::2].reset_index(drop=True), 
                     lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2')
               .sort_index(axis=1)
               .drop('col5_2', axis=1)
      )

df1.columns = ['match_time', 'competition', 'odd1_open', 'odd1_close', 'odd2_open', 'odd2_close', 'odd3_open', 'odd3_close', 'movement']
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)


    match_time    competition  odd1_open  odd1_close  odd2_open  odd2_close  odd3_open  odd3_close movement
0  05/22 16:30  Croatia 3.HNL      1.200       4.333        6.0         5.0        9.0         1.5  500.00%
1  05/23 14:00   Kosovo Super      1.222       1.444        5.5         4.5        9.0         5.0   80.00%
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is via boolean masking and `concat()` method:

Firstly create a mask:

```
mask=df['col1'].str[0].str.isnumeric()
```

Then:

```
result=pd.concat((df[mask].reset_index(drop=True),df[~mask].reset_index(drop=True)),axis=1,ignore_index=True).dropna(how='all',axis=1)
```

Finally rename columns:

```
result.columns = ['match_time', 'competition', 'odd1_open', 'odd1_close', 'odd2_open', 'odd2_close', 'odd3_open', 'odd3_close', 'movement']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat vertically odd with even rows, use some simple column ordering + rename them.

```py
import numpy as np
id = np.arange(len(df)) % 2
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.iloc[id==0].rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, np.arange(len(df.columns))*2))).reset_index(drop=True),
        df.iloc[id==1].rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, np.arange(len(df.columns))*2+1))).reset_index(drop=True),
    ], 
    axis=1,
)
df = df.loc[:, np.arange(len(df.columns)-1)]
df.columns = ['match_time', 'competition', 'odd1_open', 'odd1_close',
              'odd2_open', 'odd2_close', 'odd3_open', 'odd3_close', 'movement']
```

Output:

```py
    match_time    competition  ...  odd3_close  movement
0  05/22 16:30  Croatia 3.HNL  ...         1.5   500.00%
1  05/23 14:00   Kosovo Super  ...         5.0    80.00%
```